# Menu Image On Hover CSS or jQuery Issue In WordPress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am facing an issue. I have set an image for every single sub menu by using WordPress plugin. I am able to show the image on menu hover but it is looking very weird. I am guessing it is whether CSS or Jquery Issue.

http://luxofdubai.com/development/moonstone/product-category/pendants-contemporary/

This is the website Link. If you mouse over on products menu then hover on pendant menu trendy and contemporary. You will understand what kind of issue I am facing. I want a smooth solution. This is jquery code but I think it's CSS issue. There are 2 images for menu I just hide the normal one and only show the hovering one when you hover on menu.

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {



    jQuery(".menu-image").hide();
    jQuery(".hovered-image").hide();

    //Pendant Trendy //
    jQuery(".mptrendy a .menu-image-title").addClass("mptrendyimg");
    jQuery(".mptrendy a .hovered-image").addClass("trendpimage");





        jQuery('.mptrendyimg').mouseover(function () {


          jQuery(".trendpimage").show();

        });

        jQuery('.mptrendyimg').mouseout(function () {


          jQuery(".trendpimage").hide();

        });

        // end Pendant Trendy //
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class mptrendyimg to < a > since it is parent element for images :

```
    jQuery(".mptrendy a").addClass("mptrendyimg");
```

and also use mouseenter instead of mouseover

```
jQuery('.mptrendyimg').mouseenter(function () {

     jQuery(".trendpimage").show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but somehow if apply a class on anchor then it is not showing image on hover. I apply a class on main span and it is now somewhat better. But i think it should be more smooth. First element of the pendant submenu is still little weird.